# Adding large CSV datasets with null values to a postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, null

I have two large datasets (one with 150 million rows, one with 80 million) and I'm having a ton of trouble adding them to my postgres database.

My main issue is that there are a handful of entries that are blank (""), or null ("NULL"). Postgres doesn't like when I try to import them, and I'll usually get an error like:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

or

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "NULL"
```

Is there a way to easily go through the CSV files to change blank or NULL values to 0? Alternatively, is there a postgres data type that will allow blanks, NULLs and numbers?

It's worth noting that I'm dealing with a pretty old version of postgres (8.1.23). I'm using the copy function:

```
\copy TABLE from FILENAME.csv delimiter ','
```

Thank you!

Comment: yes - it is called `text`. after importing to text, insert into real table select  with `case when text_column = '' then  0 when text_column = 'NULL' then null else text_column end`

Comment: @Vao Tsun So, set the offending column's data type to text and then import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vao Tsun, I've learned that changing the data type to text for the columns with null or blank values solved my problem.